# stop use eventsource being resubscribed to in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-sent-events

I have a simple example consisting of an server-sent-event server sending updates every 5 seconds, and a react app listening to it. The react app seemingly adds a new listener every time `useEffect` is called, whilst keeping the old ones, this obviously crashes the app quite fast.

I've tried adding a listening state variable and only doing the subscribe if not listening, as well as only having the `useEffect` being triggered when the page first loads. In these cases the data stops being updated correctly.

#### server.js

```
const http = require("http");

http
  .createServer((request, response) => {
    console.log("Requested url: " + request.url);

    if (request.url.toLowerCase() === "/events") {
      response.writeHead(200, {
        Connection: "keep-alive",
        "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      });

      setInterval(() => {
        console.log('interval')
        response.write("event: scan\n");
        response.write("\n\n");
      }, 5000);
    }

  })
  .listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:5000/");
  });
```

#### App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([0])
  const [eventSource, setEventSource] = useState(new EventSource("http://127.0.0.1:5000/events"));

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('render')
    eventSource.addEventListener('scan', event => {
      setData([data[0] + 1, ...data]);
    });

  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div> { data } </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it is much more complicated that I initially thought, so instead of reinventing the wheel I found the package [react-hooks-sse](https://github.com/samouss/react-hooks-sse). The solution then looks like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSSE, SSEProvider } from 'react-hooks-sse';

import './App.css';


const Component = () => {
  const state = useSSE('scan');
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() =>{
    if (state) {
    setData([state.data.some.value ,...data]);
  }

}, [state])

return data
}

function App() {

  return (
    <SSEProvider endpoint="http://127.0.0.1:5000/events" >
        <Component />
    </SSEProvider>
);
}

export default App;
```

The `state` variable is technically just the latest message received from the server.